# How can free up a stiff drive-belt tensioner. Is there a suitable spray or lubricant I can use?

Tags: renault, lubrication, belt-tensioner, tensioner, k7m

I have a drive-belt tensioner, on a K7M 1.6 8v, which was initially not moving to allow me to re-place the serpentine-/drive-belt.

I managed to get it moving, but it's still a little stiff.

Can apply some lubricant to free it up a bit more, before I refit the drive belt?

If so, what would be a suitable type of lubricant, and where precisely should I be applying it?

Comment: It's probably worn and in need of replacement.  You might get some additional life out of it if you can remove and disassemble it and lube the pivot.  I'd use grease.

Comment: I decided To replace the old one with a new one.